# Connect Android to Nodejs

Tags: android, node.js

I am trying to connect nodejs backend and android frontend. I use nodejs to write api with port 3000 and I use android to call the server side api but it always fails to connect to the server, what should I do now. Help me please!!!!!!

This is Client(Android)

```
package com.hieunguyen.souq.utils;
public class Constant {
public static String LOCALHOST = "http://localhost:3000/";
public static String PRODUCT = "product";
public static String ORDER = "order";
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 88;
public static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 100;
public static final int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE = 200;
public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 300;
public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 400;
public static String PRODUCT_ID = "ProductId";
public static String CATEGORY = "Category";
public static String EMAIL = "email";
public static String OTP = "otp";
public static String PRODUCTID = "Product_id";
public static String KEYWORD = "keyword";
}
```

This is Server(Nodejs)

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express()
app.use('/storage_user', express.static('storage_user'));
app.use('/storage_product', express.static('storage_product'));
app.use('/storage_poster', express.static('storage_poster'));
const userRouter = require('./api/routes/users')
const productRouter = require('./api/routes/products')
const favoriteRouter = require('./api/routes/favorites')
const cartRouter = require('./api/routes/carts')
const historyRouter = require('./api/routes/history')
const reviewRouter = require('./api/routes/review')
const posterRouter = require('./api/routes/posters')
const addressRouter = require('./api/routes/address')
const orderRouter = require('./api/routes/orders')
const port = 3000
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/users', userRouter)
app.use('/products', productRouter)
app.use('/favorites', favoriteRouter)
app.use('/carts', cartRouter)
app.use('/history', historyRouter)
app.use('/review', reviewRouter)
app.use('/posters', posterRouter)
app.use('/address', addressRouter)
app.use('/orders', orderRouter)
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server đã khởi động!"))
```

When I run server and test on postman is ok(Localhost:3000/)
But when I run on client it's always error failed to connect to localhost:3000/ in server :((((. I don't know how to fix that!!!!. Please help me!!!! Sorry my English not good

Comment: Please put all relevant code into the question as text, don't use links to images.

Comment: Oh!! Sorry @Henry I Fixed this post!!! Please help me!

Comment: When you use `localhost` on an android device (or any other computer), this refers to the device itself. Use an IP address (or name) under which your server is known in the network.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things I think may have occurred.
First of all, localhost is currently running on your local computer, you need to config [port forwarding](https://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) on your router in order to be accessible in your local network.
Secondly, you may want to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) because your front end and back end is not hosting on the same domain.

Comment: So what should I do now, Can you say clearer please? Thank you so much